# Shrinking xerces' ElementStack

Tags: java, xml, memory, xerces

Recently, I observed an OutOfMemory condition on an application of mine. Turns out the user was going through an XML file using [javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html).

The biggest object in the heap was `XMLStreamReaderImpl.fScanner.fElementStack` of type   `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$ElementStack`.

From my naive reading of the code, `ElementStack` never decreases it's `fElements` array, but grows it as nodes are pushed into it. Is that unavoidable?

I'm suspicious of this as the JDK used in the application (1.8.0.74) has a `ElementStack2` class that doesn't appear to have this unbounded array but never is actually used in code.

So my question really is - since I can't go back in the stream, can I tell `ElementStack` to lose it's (to me) unnecessary `QName` entries?

Comment: Before investigating more, have you tried the last compatible version of Xerces ? Xerces had multiple huge bugs in this style.
Besides, can you precise the used version ?

Comment: Definitely use Apache Xerces in preference to the version in the JDK - it has been much better maintained over the years.

Comment: @davidhxxx I'm using the version packaged with jdk-1.8.0.74, adding that to the question.

Comment: @MichaelKay I'll need to dig into this deeper. We *have* `xercesImpl` on the classpath, I'm currently unsure why the system would have picked the internal version.

Comment: Please note that the current version (2.11.0) of Apache Xerces-J does not have a native implementation of javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader.